# Style not setting when returning string from function for ngStyle

Tags: angular

I am trying to set styles for a div container using the ngStyle tag. The end goal is to interpolate based on the properties of box, however I can't even seem to set the style using a static string while returning it from my getStyle function.

I have tried every combination I could think of in the ng-style arguments.

```html
<div class="bounding-box"  *ngFor="let boxs of bList [ngStyle]="getStyle(boxs)" ></div>
```

```
getStyle = (box) => {
    var boxStyle = "{'height.px': 30','width.px': '30','background-color': 'red','left.px': '30','top.px': '30',opacity: '0.20'}";
    return boxStyle;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a string which contains object structure replace it with an object since [`NgStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) accepts a key-value paired object.

```
getStyle = (box) => {
  var boxStyle = {'height.px': 30','width.px': '30','background-color': 'red','left.px': '30','top.px': '30',opacity: '0.20'};
  return boxStyle;
}
```